# correct position of "aligned with" in the sentnece

Tags: grammar

Which one (if any) is correct?

1. partial discharge rate aligned with the total discharged rate can be determined.
2. partial discharge rate can be determined aligned with the total discharged rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use **neither.**  Some of the sentences in my list are nearly identical to the ones in yours, but I slightly modified them to make them grammatical and natural.

Instead, I would use one of the following:

1. The partial discharge rate can be determined when aligned with the total discharge rate.
2. The partial discharge rate aligned with the total discharge rate can be determined.
3. When aligned with the total discharge rate, the partial discharge rate can be determined.
4. When the partial discharge rate is aligned with the total discharge rate, the former can be determined.
5. When the partial and total discharge rates are aligned, the former can be determined.
6. The partial discharge rate, when aligned with the total discharge rate, can be determined.
7. The partial discharge rate, aligned with the total discharge rate, can be determined.

**Note:** my list may not be exhaustive, but there are definitely enough options to choose from.